# Execute files in ubuntu with the filetype executable (application/x-executable)

Tags: ubuntu

as mentioned in the title, I downloaded a file for a sensor control center that is marked for Ubuntu users.

It has the following file type in the explorer "executable (application/x-executable)"

Does anybody know how I can open it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

1. open the terminal (`ctrl`+`alt`+`t`)
2. track the file with `executable (application/x-executable)` properties using `cd` command. This is same as `.exe` format in Windows OS
3. use the command: `chmod a+x file_name` , remember only `chmod +x file_name` may also works
4. now type `./file_name`, note that you might also need `sudo` mode
5. press `ctrl`+`z` to return to the terminal

Hope that helps.